# gluPerspective in what situation will the vertex can be seen?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

i'm trying to wrote a self-practicing program to test if my knowledge is correct or not. but now I found a problem on perspective view

I'm using new glfw 3 :)

```cpp
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

    //Pressing A key to pull the object up one unit 
    if( key==65 && action==GLFW_PRESS){
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    init();
    GLFWwindow *window=initWindow(800, 600, "Projection Testing");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,800/ static_cast<float>(600), 4, 10);
    //glOrtho(0, width/ (float)height, 0, 1, -10, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glVertex3f(0,0,0); 
        glVertex3f(800/ static_cast<float>(600),0,0);
        glVertex3f(800/ static_cast<float>(600),1,0); 
        glVertex3f(0,1,0);


        glEnd();


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

notice here

```
gluPerspective(90,800/ static_cast<float>(600), near clipping plane, 10);
```

I'm pretty sure other code else is correct...

my eye is set at position (0, 0, 5) and looking at (0, 0, 0) with FOV=60 degree.

I know the object must be in the frustum to be seen.
if I set near clipping plane to 4, it takes me 2 times pressing A key to make the square disappear(the second time make the object out of the frustum)
if I set it to 2, it takes me 4 times pressing A key to make the square disappear

however if I set it to 1, it take 4 times not 5 times, I can't figure it out why

sorry for my bad english..

Comment: One more question please, why the combination of near and far do not affect the size of the projected square on the screen???

Comment: Because it's a flat plane and you are trying to put it on the other plane, so sometimes it ends up on one side and sometimes on the other due to float roundings.

Comment: And the answer to Q in comment is: draw yourself a frustum. When you move the near plane, the distance to it is taken into account. Far plane is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I then modified the eye position to (0,0,5.1)... it finally took 5 time when near plane is 1.. yeah it is all about float rounding!!!

Comment: But nothing changes on the projected size when I change the value of near.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Since my blind shot made while still half-asleep through my mobile phone was correct, here's the answer in proper form:</sub>

#### First question

The results are different because of floating-point number roundings. What you are doing right here is putting the plane (object without depth) on the same depth that your clipping plane is on. This is something you want to avoid in general, as it results in problems like [Z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) or inconsistencies like in your case.

Rule of thumb is that you should never compare floats for equality, rather for subequality, though in this case, having no option to set that, I would simply refrain from drawing with Z equal to the clip-Z (as you remarked in your comment.

#### Second question

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/ViewFrustum.svg/]

As you can see, there's a clearly defined point of origin. You asked

> why the combination of near and far do not affect the size of the projected square?

In short, it's because *the shape* of the frustum doesn't change. When you move the `near` plane, all the calculations are based on the distance from that plane to origin. That is actually the reason why we can't have a clipping plane at `Z = 0` (it would imply that the distance from origin to plane is 0, and since we wan't to divide by that number, it creates obvious problems). You'd need to look at perspective calculation equations to really get that, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection#Diagram) explains it better than me.

Comment: I think i should try to implement perspective projection my self without opengl's help :) anyway, thank you for detailed answer

Comment: @TimHsu Take a look at GLM library. It's OpenSource and might help you test the stuff you write yourself.